# VBA Syntax Update for Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

This might be a 32-bit vs 64-bit thing, but I need help debugging this code that newer versions of Excel cannot run, but Excel 2003 can. Was there a syntax update in VBA between those versions that's causing this code not to compile?

The debugger stops with the line:

```
With Selection.QueryTable
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Is it not *compiling* or is it failing at *runtime*?  You mention "compile," but you also mention "debugger" (implying runtime).  What is the exact error message?  Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41289607/edit) to add detail, including the context of this statement, rather than replying in a comment.  Thanks!  -- Also, check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.

Comment: "The debugger stops" is not a helpful description of the error. The code is fine per se but may fail at runtime depending on the current value of `Selection`.

Comment: Try `With Selection.Listobject.Querytable`

Comment: Rewrite that code so that it doesn't rely on `Selection` (and `.Select`, and `.Activate`). That crap is only good for the macro recorder.

Comment: FWIW, nobody can answer this question without making assumptions, until we know what the `Selection` is at the moment it blows up.

Comment: So I made an answer *with assumptions*. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6):

> *Was there a syntax update in VBA between those versions that's causing this code not to compile?*

No. The code compiles fine, `Selection` is just about any `Object` out there, whatever member you query it with is going to be late-bound resolved, at run-time.

There *was* an addition to the Excel object model between 2003 and 2007: <s>the `ListObject` was introduced, but the `QueryTable` wasn't removed, it's still a member of the `Range` class. But it's also now a member of the `ListObject` class:</s>

Scratch the above, see [@GSerg's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289607/vba-syntax-update-for-excel-2016/41290127#comment69788010_41290127):

> *ListObject exists in Excel 2003, and it already has the QueryTable property. It does not work there though because in 2003 you cannot create a list object around a query table. Starting with Excel 2007 that became not only possible, but the default when creating a query table, and starting with Excel 2016 a query table without a listobject around it is going to permanently destroy your formulas as soon as the query happens to return no rows*

[image: Object Browser: search results for "QueryTable"]

Your code works off `Selection`, which is a terrible idea - that's what the macro recorder records, but that doesn't mean that's the best way to do anything whatsoever.

If your "query table" looks anything like this:

[image: yep, that's a ListObject]

And the Ribbon has a "Table Tools" tab when you're in it, ...then it's a `ListObject`. And if your `Selection` is inside that table, then `Selection.QueryTable` isn't going to cut it, you need to access it via the `Selection.ListObject`, as was suggested in comments:

```
With Selection.ListObject.QueryTable
```

But that's still a terrible idea, because your code is terribly frail.

Instead, use objects. Look at the *Project Explorer* toolwindow (Ctrl+R), and locate your worksheet; select it, then look at the *properties* toolwindow (F4); **give it a name**: replace its default `(Name)` property with something meaningful, e.g. `MySuperImportantSheet`.

Now you can refer to that sheet in VBA code using that identifier. Assuming there's only 1 "query table" on that sheet, this `With` block will be much more robust:

```
If MySuperImportantSheet.ListObjects.Count <> 1 Then
    'handle unexpected weirdness
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = MySuperImportantSheet.ListObjects(1)
With tbl.QueryTable
    'whatever you wanted to do with it
End With
```

Comment: That's a nice answer. If anybody wants to take it one more level and test whether, in fact, the ListObject has a QueryTable, you could check out this post of mine: [Four ListObject QueryTable Tests – Each Better Than the Last](http://yoursumbuddy.com/four-listobject-querytable-tests-better-last).

Comment: `ListObject` exists in Excel 2003, and it already has the `QueryTable` property. It does not work there though because in 2003 you cannot create a list object around a query table. Starting with Excel 2007 that became not only possible, but the default when creating a query table, and starting with Excel 2016 a query table *without* a listobject around it is going to permanently destroy your formulas as soon as the query happens to return no rows (a fun little bug I have failed to get MS to fix).